# How to prove the equivalence of the following Markov property?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-process

$X$ is a stochastic process, $\mathcal{F}_t=\sigma(X_s: s\leq t), \mathcal{G}_t=\sigma(X_s: s\geq t)$, prove that the following statements are equivalent:

1. $X$ has Markov property.
2. $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B|X_t)=\mathbb{P}(A|X_t)\mathbb{P}(B|X_t)$ for $A\in \mathcal{G}_t, B\in \mathcal{F}_t$.
3. $\mathbb{P}(B|\mathcal{G}_t)=\mathbb{P}(B|X_t)$ for $B\in \mathcal{F}_t$.

I can prove $1\Rightarrow 2$: Because of Markov property, we have $\mathbb{P}(A|\mathcal{F}_t)=\mathbb{P}(A|X_t)$ for $A\in \mathcal{G}_t$, then

\begin{split}
\mathbb{P}(A\cap B|X_t)&=\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{P}(A\cap B|\mathcal{F}_t)|X_t)=\mathbb{E}(1_B\mathbb{P}(A|\mathcal{F}_t)|X_t)\\
&=\mathbb{E}(1_B\mathbb{P}(A|X_t)|X_t)=\mathbb{P}(A|X_t)\mathbb{P}(B|X_t).
\end{split}

But how to prove $2\Rightarrow 3$? I want to take the expectation to both sides in 2, then

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{P}(A\cap B|X_t))=\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)=\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{P}(A|X_t)\mathbb{P}(B|X_t)). 
\end{equation}
If $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)=\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{P}(B|X_t)1_A), A\in \mathcal{G}_t$, then 3 holds. But is there $\mathbb{P}(A|X_t)=1_A$ in the expectation? Or another way, take the condition expectation with respect to $\mathcal{G}_t$:

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{P}(A\cap B|X_t)|\mathcal{G}_t)=\mathbb{E}(1_A\mathbb{P}(B|\mathcal{G}_t)|X_t)=\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{P}(A|X_t)\mathbb{P}(B|X_t)|\mathcal{G}_t)=\mathbb{P}(A|X_t)\mathbb{P}(B|X_t). 
\end{equation}
and how to get 3 from $\mathbb{E}(1_A\mathbb{P}(B|\mathcal{G}_t)|X_t)=\mathbb{P}(A|X_t)\mathbb{P}(B|X_t)$?

And how to prove $3\Rightarrow 1$? Thank you very much!

Comment: I might try to show that 1 = 2 and 1 = 3. I would try brute force arguments, which are pretty much guaranteed to work, given the simplicity of 2 and 3.

Comment: @Kurt G.: It comes from a chinese book, this exercise is meant to illustrate that the future and past of the Markov process are symmetric. The hints of 2 to 3, a exercise solution gives, is taking the expectation on both sides in 2, and can get $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{P}(B|X_t); A], \forall A\in \mathcal{E}$, where $\mathcal{E}$ is the sigma algebra of the state space $E$. So 3 holds. I am not sure if it is right and can't undertand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before we start recall the measure theoretic Lemma that
for any ${\cal H}$-measurable nonnegative random variable $Y$ there exists an increasing sequence of simple random variables
$$
Z_n=\sum_{i=1}^nh^n_i\,1_{H^n_i}\,,\quad h^n_i\in[0,+\infty)\,,\quad H^n_i\in{\cal H}
$$
such that $Z_n\uparrow Y\,.$ See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2943834/approximation-of-measurable-function-via-simple-functions-proof?rq=1).

Recall further that the conditional expectation $\mathbb E[U\,|\,{\cal H}]$ is defined as the (a.s.  unique) ${\cal H}$-measurable random variable
that satisfies
$$
\mathbb E\Big[\mathbb E[U\,|\,{\cal H}]\,1_H\Big]=\mathbb E[U1_H]\,,\quad \forall H\in{\cal H}\,.
$$
From the measure theoretic Lemma it follows by monotone convergence that
$$\tag{*}
\mathbb E\Big[\mathbb E[U\,|\,{\cal H}]\,Y\Big]=\mathbb E[UY]\,,\quad \forall Y\;{\cal H}\text{-measurable nonnegative}\,.
$$

- I will use this a couple of times.
- You showed correctly 1$\Rightarrow$2.

I now show 2$\Rightarrow$3: Let $A\in{\cal G}_t\,.$
Since $\mathbb P(B\,|\,X_t)$ is $\sigma(X_t)$-measurable we can use it as $Y$ in (*) and  have (with $U=1_A$ and ${\cal H}=\sigma(X_t)$)
$$
\mathbb E\big[\underbrace{\mathbb P(B\,|\,X_t)}1_A\big]=
\mathbb E\Big[\mathbb P(B\,|\,X_t)\,\mathbb P(A\,|\,X_t)\Big]
\stackrel{2}{=}\mathbb P(A\cap B)\,.
$$
Since $\mathbb P(B\,|\,{\cal G}_t)$ is defined as the unique (up to a.s.)
${\cal G}_t$-measurable random variable that satisfies
$$
\mathbb P(A\cap B)=\mathbb E\big[\underbrace{\mathbb P(B\,|\,{\cal G}_t)}1_A\big]\,\quad\forall A\in{\cal G}_t
$$
we have therefore shown that $\mathbb P(B\,|\,{\cal G}_t)$ must
almost surely equal $P(B\,|\,X_t)$ as the latter is clearly ${\cal G}_t$-measurable.

The proof of 2$\Rightarrow$1 is similar, in fact, symmetric:
Let $B\in{\cal F}_t\,.$
Since $\mathbb P(A\,|\,X_t)$ is $\sigma(X_t)$-measurable we have
$$
\mathbb E\big[\mathbb P(A\,|\,X_t)1_B\big]=
\mathbb E\Big[\mathbb P(B\,|\,X_t)\,\mathbb P(A\,|\,X_t)\Big]
\stackrel{2}{=}\mathbb P(A\cap B)\,.
$$
Like in the previous case this shows
$\mathbb P(A\,|\,{\cal F}_t)$ must
almost surely equal $P(A\,|\,X_t)$ which is the Markov property.

It remains to show 3$\Rightarrow$2. This is similar (symmetric) to 1$\Rightarrow$2:
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(A\cap B\,|\,X_t)&=\mathbb E\Big[\mathbb P(A\cap B\,|\,{\cal G}_t)\,\Big|\,X_t\Big]=
\mathbb E\Big[1_A\,\mathbb P(B\,|\,{\cal G}_t)\,\Big|\,X_t\Big]\\
&\stackrel{3}=\mathbb E\Big[1_A\,\mathbb P(B\,|\,X_t)\,\Big|\,X_t\Big]\\
&=\mathbb P(A\,|\,X_t)\,\mathbb P(B\,|\,X_t)\,.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but from 2 to 3, we don‘t have the Markov property. And it also give me some hints, but I still can't understand how to get $\mathbb{P}(B|\mathcal{G}_t)=\mathbb{P}(B|X_t)$ from $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{P}(B|\mathcal{G}_t)1_A|X_t]]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{P}(A\cap B|X_t)]$.

Comment: The weaker version 1 to 3 should be correct now. Let's digest that and keep struggling.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know why $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{P}(B|X_t)1_A]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{P}(B|X_t)\mathbb{P}(A|X_t)]$ before, that is your first step. And now I know taking the condition expectation w.r.t $X_t$ and taking the expectation again.

Comment: I am thanking you for that interesting question. Even at my age one learns something new. If there is still anything unclear let me know. The first step is a fairly simple generalization of the definition of $\mathbb P(A\,|\,X_t)\,.$ Morale: what holds for indicator functions of sets $C\in\sigma(X_t)$ holds for nonnegative $\sigma(X_t)$-measurable random variables (here $\mathbb P(B\,|\,X_t)\,)\,.$

Comment: Yeah, it's a new and interesting perspective for me, considering the first step as the definition of $\mathbb{P}(A|X_t)$.

Comment: @Syruphhh It is not the definition but follows easily from it and from a measure theoretic Lemma that I now added to the answer.